# Blind Targeting Exception on Windows Machines

Tags: windows, webpack, vaadin, babel-loader

When deploying our Vaadin 14 Java application locally, webpack most of the time throws an error when done on a windows machine. On Mac and Linux machines, it works perfectly fine. This is the error I get on startup:

```
[ERROR][webpack][dev-webpack] ERROR in ./styles/vaadin/vaadin-context-menu-list-box.scss
[ERROR][webpack][dev-webpack] Module not found: Error: Encountered unexpected blind targeting request for C:\Users\efranke\Projekte\Java\Tracy\tracy-web\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--4-0!C:\Users\efranke\Projekte\Java\Tracy\tracy-web\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6!C:\Users\efranke\Projekte\Java\Tracy\tracy-web\node_modules\css-loader\dist\runtime\api.js.Please see http://github.com/DanielSchaffer/webpack-babel-multi-target-plugin#blind-targeting for more information.
[ERROR][webpack][dev-webpack]  @ ./styles/vaadin/vaadin-context-menu-list-box.scss 1:27-90
[ERROR][webpack][dev-webpack]  @ ../target/frontend/generated-flow-imports.js
[ERROR][webpack][dev-webpack] i ?wdm?: Failed to compile.
[ERROR][webpack][dev-webpack] 
------------------ Frontend compilation failed. -----------------
```

If we do this on a Mac or Linux machine, it works fine 100% of the time.

Webpack-Config:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const flowDefaults = require('./webpack.generated.js');

module.exports = merge(flowDefaults, {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: [
                            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
                            '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
                                {decoratorsBeforeExport: true}],
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.lcss$/, //match any lit css files (.lcss)
                use: [{
                    loader: 'lit-scss-loader',
                    options: {
                        minify: true, // defaults to false

                    },
                }, 'extract-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "no-name",
  "description": "Inhouse reporting as a service tool",
  "version": "14.0.5",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://gitlab.bonprix.work/vt-ec-cp-mdp/tracy.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@polymer/iron-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "@polymer/polymer": "3.2.0",
    "@vaadin/flow-deps": "./target/frontend",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10",
    "bootstrap-webcomponents": "^4.3.0",
    "bower": "^1.8.8",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "lit-element": "^2.2.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "polymer-modulizer": "^0.4.3",
    "style-loader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.2.10",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "extract-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "lit-scss-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "raw-loader": "3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "2.1.4",
    "typescript": "3.5.3",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-babel-multi-target-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.3.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1"
  },
  "vaadinAppPackageHash": "8c2fd8a52a1f047cb3d5fe048da8b8fc57e3c5626c86edad9032171f7a75a2c1",
  "vaadin": {
    "disableUsageStatistics": true
  }
}
```

I already tried to manually reload all neccessary dependencies as described [here](https://medium.com/@jeffrey.allen.lewis/the-ultimate-2018-webpack-4-and-babel-setup-guide-npm-yarn-dependencies-compared-entry-points-866b577da6a), invalidating caches (npm cache clean --force) and deleting the node_modules folder. Because it didn't solve the problem and the fact that it works perfectly fine on Mac and Linux machines leads me to the assumption, that this is a Windows specific problem.

Comment: Are you using Vaadin 14.0.x release or Vaadin 14.1.x release? 14.1 has newer version of "webpack-babel-multi-target-plugin", which probably solves the problem.

Comment: We indeed used Vaadin 14.0.12. The upgrade to 14.1.5 solved the problem. I still do not know what caused the error. But I'm happy it is fixed anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Vaadin version upgrade from 14.0.12 to 14.1.5 solved the problem. In this release, Vaadin uses newer dependencies for i.e. the "webpack-babel-multi-target-plugin". Updating this version manually did not help. Thanks to Tatu Lund for finding the solution.